# How to convert a date time to a users time zone in PHP

Tags: php

I have a date time entered in the timezone UTC+0 and in the format

```
$curDate = date("Y-m-d");
$curTime = date("g:i a");
```

What I want is, detect the timezone of the visiting user.

After that convert the date and time into his/her time zone and show the date time in their timezone.

Comment: You need to detect the timezone of visiting user first and then ask a question about converting.

Comment: Agree with @Sajad, you cant just convert datetime on the fly, first step be checking user geo location and next step is convert datetime

Answer (score 2):

```
$utc_date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d G:i',
    '2011-04-27 02:45',
    new DateTimeZone('UTC')
);

$acst_date = clone $utc_date; // we don't want PHP's default pass object by reference here
$acst_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Australia/Yancowinna'));

echo 'UTC:  ' . $utc_date->format('Y-m-d g:i A');  // UTC:  2011-04-27 2:45 AM
echo 'ACST: ' . $acst_date->format('Y-m-d g:i A'); // ACST: 2011-04-27 12:15 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `http://ipinfodb.com/` to detect users localization and as a result users timezone, for instance:

```
function geoLocalization($ip, $api_key)
{
  $params = @file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v2/ip_query.php?key=".$api_key."&ip=".$ip."&timezone=true");
  $fields = @new SimpleXMLElement($params);
  foreach($fields as $field => $val) {
      $result[(string)$field] = (string)$val;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

as you get users localization you can use `date_default_timezone_set` to set the timezone.
It is good practice to let your users to overwrite this.

You can find all timezones on this site:
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 1):

For php +5.3 you can use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). But for previous versions of php, You should use of `strtotime()`. here is a example:

```
$curDate = date('l, F d y h:i:s');
$curDate = strtotime($curDate);
$new = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $curDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either force the user to provide you the timezone as the very first thing.

Or

Gets request's IPAddr, then geolocation, then tmezone.

The second option is dependent upon 3rd party libraries and 3rd part servers.